Counterexample for the 1-optimal matching algorithm in Gabow's and Tarjan's paper on scaling algorithms for networks
Context
I am reading Faster scaling algorithms for network problems by Gabow and Tarjan where I am researching part 2: "Matching and extensions". However, I am a bit confused with the algorithm at the bottom of page 6. On page 7 there a claim that throughout this algorithm the matching $M$ remains 1-feasible, without much further explanation. I found a counterexample but I might have missed something. If so, can someone give some pointers?
Counterexample
Take the following weighted bipartite graph.
    2
A1 --- B1
  1\ /4
   / \
A2 --- B2
    2

The costs of the edges are integers of at least $-1$, so the input is OK.
The algorithm starts by initializing all dual variables to $0$.
Iteration 1
The first step of the loop of the algorithm is searching a maximal set of vertex-disjoint augmenting paths of eligible edges. There are no eligible edges so now we go to step 2.
In step 2 of the algorithm we search a forest $\mathcal{F}$ of eligible edges, with roots $V_0 \setminus M$. The forest is $\mathcal{F} = \{(A_1), (A_2)\}$. Now a dual adjustment is done with the adjustment quantity $\delta = cl(A_1, B_2) - y(A_1) - y(B_2) = 1 + 1 - 0 - 0 = 2$ which gives the following dual variables:
2 A1   B1 0

2 A2   B2 0

Now $\mathcal{F} = \{(A_1, (B_2)), (A_2)\}$ and $(A_1, B_2)$ is a free eligible edge so we can go back to step 1
Iteration 2
After the first step we have $M = \{(A_1, B_2)\}$ and the duals are
2 A1   B1 0

2 A2   B2 -1

For step 2 $\mathcal{F} = {(A_2)}$ so $\delta = cl(A_2, B_2) - y(A_2) - y(B_2) = 2$. Adjusting the duals gives
2 A1   B1 0

4 A2   B2 -1

The edge $(A_2, B_2)$ can now be added to $\mathcal{F}$ so $\mathcal{F}$ becomes $\{(A_2, (B_2))\}$ but $B_2$ is not a free vertex, so another dual adjustment is necessary. There is only one edge to take into account for $\delta$, so $\delta = 1$. Now, all duals that are in $\mathcal{F}$ must be adjusted with $1 \cdot \delta$ if the vertex is in $V_0$ and $-1 \cdot \delta$ if the vertex is in $V_1$.
The weights, matching and duals now look like this
\\ -> edge in matching
      2
2 A1 --- B1 0
   1\\ /4
     / \\
5 A2 --- B2 -2
      2

Now $M$ is not a 1-feasible matching anymore.

It may be a good idea to contact Hal Gabow. https://home.cs.colorado.edu/~hal/ He is generally quite forthcoming.

@ChandraChekuri I have done that a few of days ago together with two more questions. He has pointed me to this paper with follow-up work, but I still have to look at all the details
